# How can I filter for entries that do NOT contain a key-value pair within a nested array

Tags: json, select, jq, negation

Let's say I have the following JSON output:

```
{
 "Stacks": [
        {
            "StackName": "hello-world",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "environment",
                    "Value": "sandbox"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Joe Shmo",
                    "Value": "Dev"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "StackName": "hello-man",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "environment",
                    "Value": "live"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Tandy",
                    "Value": "Dev"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I write a `jq` query to grab all `StackName`s for stacks that do *NOT* have a `Tags` value `"Key": "Joe Shmo"`? So the result would return simply `hello-man`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`contains`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#contains(element)), like this:

```
jq -r '.Stacks[]|select(.Tags|contains([{"Key": "Joe Shmo"}])|not).StackName'
```

Note: `-r` removes the quotes from output, otherwise `jq` would print `"hello-man"` (within double quotes)

Answer (score 1):

```
.Stacks[]
| select( any(.Tags[]; .Key == "Joe Shmo" ) | not)
| .StackName
```

This checks for equality efficiently (`any` has short-circuit semantics), whereas `contains` would check for containment.

Comment: I'm checking if `.Tags` contains an object with the _exact_ key "Joe Shmo". At least I think my code is doing that

Comment: omg! I now see what you mean. Seriously, this is prone to be misunderstood. Especially since the manual doesn't mention it. If I would be the author I would place a red box into the manual: CAREFUL: this function is broken

Comment: PS: Unf. SO doesn't allow to delete an accepted answer.